# Select Records by date, Max record of date and count records

Tags: sql

Morning.
I have a table with MacAdress and date fields.

Now I want to select the records by date but only the max record of the date and also count the records selected

I am using Access currently but want to use the query in Node-red.

Is there a way of doing it in one single query?

Thanks

Here is a sample of my data

| tDate | MACAddress |
| --- | --- |
| 2023/07/30 15:12:30 | D7666176AE4E |
| 2023/07/30 15:12:42 | 808ABD4F31D7 |
| 2023/07/30 15:12:57 | C88AC7E3A1DD |
| 2023/07/30 15:13:11 | C73090FC433C |
| 2023/07/31 11:17:35 | D7666176AE4E |
| 2023/07/31 12:16:59 | 808ABD4F31D7 |
| 2023/07/31 12:17:22 | C73090FC433C |
| 2023/07/31 12:17:35 | D7666176AE4E |
| 2023/07/31 13:18:08 | C88AC7E3A1DD |
| 2023/07/31 14:21:16 | C88AC7E3A1DD |
| 2023/07/31 15:26:48 | C88AC7E3A1DD |

So I want to display it like this and also count it to tell me that there is 4 records.

| MaxOftDate | MACAddress |
| --- | --- |
| 2023/07/31 12:16:59 | 808ABD4F31D7 |
| 2023/07/31 12:17:22 | C73090FC433C |
| 2023/07/31 15:26:48 | C88AC7E3A1DD |
| 2023/07/31 12:17:35 | D7666176AE4E |

This is my query sovar:

```
    SELECT Max(Table1.tDate) AS MaxOftDate, DateValue(Table1.tDate) AS Date1, Table1.MACAddress
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY DateValue(Table1.tDate), Table1.MACAddress, DateValue([Table1].[tDate])
HAVING (((DateValue([Table1].[tDate]))=#7/31/2023#));
```

If I try to add the count like this:

```
    SELECT Max(Table1.tDate) AS MaxOftDate, DateValue(Table1.tDate) AS Date1, Table1.MACAddress, Count(Table1.MACAddress) AS CountOfMACAddress
FROM Table1
GROUP BY DateValue(Table1.tDate), Table1.MACAddress, DateValue([Table1].[tDate])
HAVING (((DateValue([Table1].[tDate]))=#7/31/2023#));
```

I get these results:

| MaxOftDate | MACAddress | CountOfMACAddress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023/07/31 12:16:59 | 808ABD4F31D7 | 1 |
| 2023/07/31 12:17:22 | C73090FC433C | 1 |
| 2023/07/31 15:26:48 | C88AC7E3A1DD | 3 |
| 2023/07/31 12:17:35 | D7666176AE4E | 2 |

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: The HAVING clause is for aggregate function conditions. Put regular conditions in a WHERE clause.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific in several ways.)

Answer (score 0):

The `HAVING` in your code needs to be a `WHERE` since you're not using an aggregate function, also the `group by` only needs the MAC Adresses, since you want `MAX` and `COUNT` for every MAC Address.

This should do the trick:

```sql
SELECT MAX(Table1.tDate) AS MaxOftDate
  ,Table1.MACAddress
  ,COUNT(Table1.tDate) AS CountOfMACAddress
FROM Table1
WHERE [Table1].[tDate]='2023-07-31'
GROUP BY Table1.MACAddress
```

Comment: WHERE comes before GROUP BY.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I edited the answer, thanks @jarlh